# Stored procedure not executing the update part until run a second time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that, when ran, does an initial insert into a a table from a view, followed by an update statement that modifies a table in the view the first select statement uses (code is below):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LFC_sp_LIT_PgmrRequestForm] 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    insert into firebird.helpdesk.dbo.tbl_program_request (Requester, Description, Priority, DateRequest,  project_status, department, category, requester_email, DueDate, Note)
    select dept_name, submitter_first_name + '-' + issue_description, severity_level, getdate(), 'Not Started', dept_name, issue_category, submitter_email, date_due, issue_details
    from ics_net..CUS_CF_PGMR_REQUEST_View
    where finalbalance = 0; 

    UPDATE ics_net..CF_Submission
    SET finalbalance = 5
    WHERE finalbalance = 0
    AND FormId = '79A807D9-230B-494C-A609-A284DBBE41B8';

END
```

This procedure is called whenever a web form is submitted, and the goal is to move the data from the web form database into our help desk database. The web form has a final balance field in the database, that is set to zero. When it is moved, we update it to a non-zero number.

What happens is that the first statement executes, but the second update never happens. Once this is called again, the first statement executes, and the second one works for the statement that was supposed to be previously updated. Things I've tried to resolve the issue are:

1. Use the ROWLOCK hint for both statements
2. I've made sure the transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED

I can't think of anything else to do, other than to use the NOLOCK hint on the select statement, but I'm very hesitant to do that. Any ideas? Thanks.

EDIT 1) Based on some discussion, I want to clarify a couple things:

1. There aren't any existing triggers on any of the tables
   underlying this query.
2. The initial select is based on a view, while the second update
   references a table that makes up the view.

Edit 2) Some more details

The view definition:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[CUS_CF_PGMR_REQUEST_View] AS 
select s.SubmissionId,
 s.FormId,
 s.SubmittedDate,
 s.UserId,
 s.Status,
 sfn.AnswerValue as [submitter_first_name],
 sub_email.AnswerValue as [submitter_email],
 dname.AnswerValue as [dept_name],
 d_due.AnswerValue as [date_due],
 i_cat.AnswerValue as [issue_category],
 sec_lev.AnswerValue as [severity_level],
 i_desc.AnswerValue as [issue_description],
 i_det.AnswerValue as [issue_details],
 s.FinalBalance
from CF_Submissions s
left outer join CF_Answers sfn on sfn.ItemID = 'df5307ca-d9a8-4c74-955e-7fe80caafdc0' 
    and sfn.SubmissionID=s.SubmissionID
left outer join CF_Answers sub_email on sub_email.ItemID = '27e8e2fd-13f8-4c5a-a6bb-bc68fa7d4af5' 
    and sub_email.SubmissionID=s.SubmissionID
left outer join CF_Answers dname on dname.ItemID = '2826ee1b-759e-4325-b0ba-32a86ed7f07a' 
    and dname.SubmissionID=s.SubmissionID
left outer join CF_Answers d_due on d_due.ItemID = '5e087866-63ce-41f1-bb32-443770fdf388' 
    and d_due.SubmissionID=s.SubmissionID
left outer join CF_Answers i_cat on i_cat.ItemID = '32be52b1-1539-4d9b-9f7c-ffb370188396' 
    and i_cat.SubmissionID=s.SubmissionID
left outer join CF_Answers sec_lev on sec_lev.ItemID = 'f795ff66-342b-4155-86d6-7655dc2b10a5' 
    and sec_lev.SubmissionID=s.SubmissionID
left outer join CF_Answers i_desc on i_desc.ItemID = '3ff0e614-bdf6-4710-9ba0-6f7356c67032' 
    and i_desc.SubmissionID=s.SubmissionID
left outer join CF_Answers i_det on i_det.ItemID = 'dd5b797d-a407-4bc7-a73c-daacb3abe660' 
    and i_det.SubmissionID=s.SubmissionID
where s.FormId = '79a807d9-230b-494c-a609-a284dbbe41b8'
```

Table Definitions Underlying The View

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CF_Answers](
    [AnswerID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [SubmissionID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [ItemID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [AnswerValue] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [MItemID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [RowIndex] [int] NULL,
    [ChildItemID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [DisplayText] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [NumericValue] [numeric](8, 2) NULL,
    [IsVisibleOnSubmit] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CF_Answers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AnswerID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CF_Submissions](
    [SubmissionID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [FormID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [SubmittedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [FinalBalance] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [WorkflowID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Status] [int] NULL,
    [TransactionID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [WaiverCode] [varchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CF_Submissions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SubmissionID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

The definition of the destination table for the insert:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_program_request](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Requester] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Priority] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [DateRequest] [datetime] NULL,
    [WorkingOn] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [CompletedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [StartDate] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [Note] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [project_status] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [hours_week] [decimal](4, 2) NULL,
    [hours_total] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [department] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [category] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [requester_email] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [DueDate] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Finally, some sample data that was pulled from the view:

SubmissionId -  B81CE5F8-A87B-42B1-9339-2B36166394AB
FormId  - 79A807D9-230B-494C-A609-A284DBBE41B8
SubmittedDate   - 1/24/2018 16:43
UserId -    58E3958A-A786-4CB9-8EDE-0837ACE187BD
Status -    1
submitter_first_name -  SM
submitter_email - email@organization
dept_name - LIT
date_due - 1/28/2018
issue_category -MISC
severity_level - LOW
issue_description - test3
issue_details - test3
FinalBalance - 0

Just to clarify, at the end of the SP, FinalBalance should equal 5. However, it isn't set to 5 until the second time it's ran, causing a double insert into the tbl_program_request table.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the two statements appear to be unrelated. `CF_Submission` is the only object that appears in the second statement, and it doesn't appear in the first. If you're saying that the second statement isn't "running" then  something else is at play here, but it isn't the SP.

Comment: Just want to clarify that the ics_net..CF_Submission is one of the tables underlying the view ics_net..CUS_CF_PGMR_REQUEST_View. It's the table that actually holds the finalbalance field.

Comment: Just firing an idea here: Could the use of a trigger solve this problem?

Comment: You have a where clause on the view of finalbalance, however, the table you update does not have a finalbalance and it cannot be a derived field as you would not be able to update the view, therefore, it must be a timing/trigger related issue.

Comment: Just tried adding an on insert trigger to the table with the insert statement that executes the update in the second part. This caused the insert to fail.

Comment: What does fail mean? Was there an error?

Comment: No errors, the update and/or insert just doesn't happen.

Comment: Without some details of the table structure and some sample data that can reproduce the issue we are left guessing. The statements are firing if you run the procedure. But they are not working as you expect because the data is preventing it from doing what you think it should.